# Altair sorting Chart

Tags: dataframe, sorting, bar-chart, altair

I'm trying to plot the data of my DataFarme in a groupedChart and I want the columns to preserve the order I gave them before. The data looks as follows (its not all there but its in the same way organized)
[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIx5U.jpg)

When I plot it I get the following Graph:
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JXlt.png)

So the months were sorted even though I specified not to sort in the chart. I used the following code:

```
chart2 = alt.Chart(melted).mark_bar().encode(
            column=alt.Column('variable',sort=None),
            x=alt.X('room',sort=None),
            y=alt.Y('value'),
            color='room',
            tooltip= ['room', 'value']
         
        )
```

Does anyone know how I could fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You've already used `sort=None`, which is the correct way to make scales in a non-faceted chart reflect the input order.

The missing piece is that faceted charts share scales by default (See [Scale and Guide Resolution](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/scale_resolve.html)), so each facet is being forced to share an order.

If you make the x scale resolution independent, then each facet should retain the input order:

```python
chart2 = alt.Chart(melted).mark_bar().encode(
            column=alt.Column('variable',sort=None),
            x=alt.X('room',sort=None),
            y=alt.Y('value'),
            color='room',
            tooltip= ['room', 'value']
         
        ).resolve_scale(x='independent')
```